# Eliminate Records Without Combination

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle8i

I have the following data in TEMP_DATA table

[image]

From these records, I would like to get only those records which are having CAT_NO 36 and 39 combination of records, ideally my expected results are as follows

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an Oracle8 instance to test but this should work:

```
select * from temp_data where prod_no in ( 
    select prod_no from temp_data where cat_no = 39 and prod_no in (
       select prod_no from temp_data where cat_no = 36 ) ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you try intersect.

```
 SELECT prod_type,
       prod_no,
       cat_no,
       prod_cat,
       text,
       prod_seq
  FROM temp_data
 WHERE prod_no IN (SELECT prod_no
                     FROM temp_data
                    WHERE cat_no = 36
                   INTERSECT
                   SELECT prod_no
                     FROM temp_data
                    WHERE cat_no = 39)
```